# Convert from string to datetime in spark?

Tags: python, pyspark, timestamp

i've tried following some of the answers on here but i think i'm doing something wrong, ideally i would like to convert my string represenation to a timestamp.

Although initially the conversation caused miliseconds to be added to the end of it. Which i didn't want so i choose this approach

data: for example is *2022-03-15T01:46:32* which i would like this representation of `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` to be converted to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

I attempted this way

```
new_df = df_geo.withColumn("timestamp", to_timestamp("timestamp", format= "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
```

Which the outcome was a bunch of null values in the timestamp column, update the reason it was coming out as nulls is due to not including 'T' in the space between day and hour.

```
df_geo.withColumn("timestamp", to_timestamp("timestamp", format= "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"))
```

This still does cause milliseconds to be added to the end of the representation, I can try data format to change the representation but then with that it will change the data type to a string whereas i want to keep it as a timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

format the date with the desired format and then cast to `timestamp`

```
input
   .withColumn("date_time_another_format",
     f.date_format('date_time_field,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
       .cast("timestamp")
   )

  /*

  INPUT
  +---+-------------------+
  |id |date_time_field    |
  +---+-------------------+
  |1  |2024-02-20T01:30:00|
  |2  |2024-02-10T05:30:45|
  +---+-------------------+

  //OUTPUT SCHEMA
  root
   |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
   |-- date_time_field: string (nullable = true)
   |-- date_time_another_format: timestamp (nullable = true)

  //OUTPUT
  +---+-------------------+------------------------+
  | id|    date_time_field|date_time_another_format|
  +---+-------------------+------------------------+
  |  1|2024-02-20T01:30:00|     2024-02-20 01:30:00|
  |  2|2024-02-10T05:30:45|     2024-02-10 05:30:45|
  +---+-------------------+------------------------+
   */
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i firgured it might have been something like this but i'm new to pyspark so still learning